# What is the correct MIME type for a tar.gz file?

Tags: tar, gzip, file-types, mime-types

What is the correct MIME type for a tar.gz file?

I've searched around and found several values being used, including:

```
application/x-gzip
application/x-gtar
application/x-tgz
```

But I could find no indication as to which of these (if any) was the correct or canonical value.

Comment: Perhaps this question will be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600229/what-content-type-header-to-use-when-serving-gzipped-files

Answer (score 108, accepted):

As of August 2012, the MIME type recommended in [RFC 6713](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6713) is `application/gzip`.

According to the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), tar is not an official media type, so a GZipped tar file is officially only a compressed file.

Hypothetically, if a tarball were an official media type and following conventions, its MIME type would be `application/tar` (file extension .tar) and its compressed version would be `application/tar+gzip` (file extensions .tar.gz and .tgz).

Comment: "application/zip" worked for me. I always thought tar.gz was just a zipped tarball.

Comment: @PJBrunet That would be an incorrect media type because `application/zip` is a different format than `application/gzip` and `tar.gz` is a _gzipped_ tarball; Zip uses multiple compression methods, not all of which are freely licensed. Perhaps you got lucky and your decompression library recognizes both formats from their data stream.

Comment: If `tar` is not an official media type, would that not make `application/x-tar+gzip` the most correct? I feel that would be more clear even if it's less... official.

Comment: Ubuntu labels XZ compressed tar as `application/x-xz-compressed-tar`. But that's not super useful as the Nautilus file picker doesn't obey non-standard mime types... the ones with "x-". In practice for HTML forms, you'd use extensions in the accept field for non standard types.

Answer (score 6):

Although most are deprecated, they are all technically correct, just different MIME types.

The correct MIME type is `application/x-gzip` according to cPanel standards.

Comment: When I rewrote the file with `application/x-gzip`, It got corrupted. But when I used `application/gzip `, it worked.

Comment: cPanel isn't a standard of anything except bad coding practices.

Comment: Same experience as Amit:```application/x-gzip``` and ```application/tar+gzip``` produced corrupted files, whereas ```application/gzip``` worked.